# pdo_sqlanywhere macOS Mojave

Tags: php, macos, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to build the PDO_SQLANYWHERE for PHP7.2 and macOS Mojave. I followed the same guide as ubuntu, which works fine me.

So I did a

```
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/PDO_SQLANYWHERE-0.1.4.tgz -O /tmp/pdo_sqlanywhere.tgz
```

and

```
mkdir -p pdo_sqlanywhere \
&& tar -C pdo_sqlanywhere -zxvf /tmp/pdo_sqlanywhere.tgz --strip 1 \
  && ( \
  cd pdo_sqlanywhere \
  && phpize \
  && ./configure \
  && make -j$(nproc) \
  && make install \
  ) \
&& rm -r pdo_sqlanywhere \
&& rm /tmp/pdo_sqlanywhere.tgz
```

but the

```
make install
```

fails with

```
duplicate symbol _pdo_sqlanywhere_globals in:
.libs/pdo_sqlanywhere.o
.libs/sqlanywhere_driver.o
duplicate symbol _pdo_sqlanywhere_globals in:
.libs/pdo_sqlanywhere.o
.libs/sqlanywhere_statement.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Would be nice to have this native on macOS.

I'm using the newest Xcode Version

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)
```

and

```
cmake version 3.12.3
```

Has anyone an idea? :-)

Thanks.